# Get 503 response from resumable upload api( v2 ) although the video has been uploaded successfully

Tags: youtube-api

when I uploaded a 150M video from my website, I came across the problem, that is:
I got 503 response instead of 201 created response from youtube, but the video has been uploaded to youtube already, since I can see it on my youtube page.

I use the apis in:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_resumable_uploads

So could someone tell me what has happened? 
What shall I do for this case?

Great thanks!

Comment: Did anyone ever solve this? Asked on 2011, it's 2013 and no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem when using the resumable upload. if i dont clarify the Content-Range in the request header, i could even upload a file with size 550MB. but if i cut the file into different chunks and upload them by different requests, with Content-Range header set. then it would end up with the same error message 503.

My guess of the answer is the header variable Content-Length. Google are expecting Content-Length to be the remaining size of the Total-Content-length. And all browser modify that value to be the actual size of the data which u sent.

For example if you are sending 3 bytes of data in 3 chunks, each chunk is 1 byte. during 1st chunk, you set Content-Length to be 3 (remaining size). but browser modify it to be 1, which makes Google to think only 1 byte left, and after the 1st chunk is sent, the service is closed, and you can not send any data to that specific upload URL anymore, thus error code 503 is returned.

so i guess the better solution is to ask Google to use other header variable than Content-Length. Or a little trick is to use still resumable upload method, but without cutting the file into parts, and without Content-Range header setting in the request. The same time when uploading, we can watch the status by calling the same UPLOAD_URL in the specific way Google Doc has described. At least I have managed uploading 550MB file successfully.